# What is the meaning of this writing on the InSight lander, and why is some in Braille?

Tags: nasa, identify-this-object, insight

I spotted this image in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32645) and a few things caught my eye.

Both images are cropped from the much larger image [PIA22540](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA22540).

### First Braille in Space?

On the left and right sides there is what looks to me to be [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) writing. What does it say?

[image]

What is Little Giant, shown below?

[image]

Comment: Puzzlingly, Little Giant is a ladder company — that’s definitely their logotype. https://littlegiantladders.com

Comment: @RussellBorogove Potentially, since the calibration plate is right on the edge of the lander, the 'little giant' is actually on a step ladder or similar that just happens to be in frame

Comment: @Jack oh, duh! I finally figured it out. This photo wasn't taken on Mars. I can't believe that it never occurred to me. That the image is 4608 x 3456 pixels should have been a clue. I just assumed that the fact that the image had a PIA number and a JPL web page https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA22540 meant that it was a "space image".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capital, Capital (Block Capitals), j, p, l

JPL

http://braillebug.afb.org/braille_deciphering.asp

> "I was thinking what else could we put on there that could be a kind
>   of code that people in the know could look at and figure out?" said
>   Bruce Banerdt, InSight's principal investigator at JPL, in an
>   interview with collectSPACE. "I thought, 'What about braille?'

http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-112618a-mars-insight-braille-jpl.html

Comment: great job, now we just have to find out the story behind it. It may in fact be the first Braille in space!

Comment: I think memorial coins for Louis Braille (inventor of Braille writing) that flew on the 2009 Hubble servicing missions had Braille writing on them.

Comment: Braille is "...a kind of code that people in the know *could look at* and figure out..."? ;-)