# Is there a list of private companies with products on NASA Mars landers?

Tags: mars, nasa, lander, manufacturing

I'm trying to create a list of all private companies which have their products on the Mars surface. To make it easier, I'm limiting my search to NASA landers.

Is there a comprehensive list of NASA contractors which includes the project name? I'm familiar with usaspending.gov -- but that begins in 2008, and does not include the project name on the award (as far as I can tell).

For example, if a company manufactured even a screw used on any lander from Viking 1 through InSight, I want to put them on my list. Is this possible? Does it exist in some form already?

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: That's basically a list of all the components.

Comment: Do you include non-US-american instruments on NASA-Landers? (e.g. French and/or German ones, like SEIS or the Mole on InSight)?

Comment: apparently Little Giant [isn't one of them](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32671/12102)

Comment: @CallMeTom I was hoping to start simple and only use Nasa Landers

Comment: @uhoh haha cool thread, thanks